# Cross compile ros minimal using Eros on Fedora 14

Tags: linux, boost, cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I use Fedora 14 and my current version of boost and boost-devel is 1.44
I have been trying to cross compile ROS using the instructions found under the Eros page. I have followed all instructions (including the tool bridge) and I have been successful in all of the steps up until the command 
 **rosprotect --pre-clean --minimal** 
I have the following output from this command: 
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example.dir/examples/example.o
Linking CXX executable ../examples/example
/home/nohemi/ros/ros_comm/utilities/rostime/lib/librostime.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread_resource_error::thread_resource_error()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [../examples/example] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/nohemi/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nohemi/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/nohemi/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2

I am not sure how to proceed. Do I need to upgrade to an older version of boost? Or do I need to change some file headers? Or maybe something else entirely?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9788/cross-compile-ros-minimal-using-eros-on-fedora-14/) by [nohemi](https://answers.ros.org/users/451/nohemi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Undefined references. Typically this happens when it looks for your cross compiled library, but picked up your native library instead. Some things to check:

- Your CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH. This is where cmake expects to search for libs and headers. If its wrong, it can fall back to native directories. Find your toolchain's library path (the one with libpthread-2.8.so in it, if you subtract the lib folder, you have the correct string.
- Make sure your cross compiled libraries are there, otherwise it may fall back to trying to use your native libraries.

If you're not using a standard [eros toolchain](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_python_tools/rostoolchain) module you may have incorrectly specified the `TOOLCHAIN_SYSROOT`, `TOOLCHAIN_INSTALL_PREFIX` (and subsequently `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`) settings when attempting to create a [custom toolchain](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_python_tools/UserDefinedToolchains) module. Refer to the latter page for more hints on how to track down your library/header paths.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0